# Get last made move from game boards

Tags: java

I have two 2D int arrays that represent game boards. (The initial board and the new board)

Content of the initial board:

```
013 | 6 0 0 0 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 6 
012 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 
011 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
010 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 
009 | 4 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 
008 | 4 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 
007 | 4 4 0 2 2 2 5 2 2 2 0 4 4 
006 | 4 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 
005 | 4 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 
004 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 
003 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
002 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 
001 | 6 0 0 0 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 6 
      A B C D E F G H I J K L M
```

Content of the new board (after applying a move):

```
013 | 6 0 0 0 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 6 
012 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 
011 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
010 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 
009 | 4 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 
008 | 4 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 
007 | 4 4 0 2 2 2 5 2 2 2 0 4 4 
006 | 4 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 
005 | 4 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 
004 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 
003 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
002 | 0 0 0 0 4 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 
001 | 6 0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 6 
      A B C D E F G H I J K L M
```

I wanna compare the two game boards to get the last fetched move. How can I determine the last made move on this board?

As you can see the last made move is: "E1 - E2" -> The pawn "E1" was put in "E2"

Is there a fast way to compare the two to determine this last made move `"E1 - E2"`

What I have:

```
    for (int y = 0; y < Board.DIMENSION; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < Board.DIMENSION; x++) {
            // Check where not equal
            if (initialBoard.grid[x][y] != newBoard.grid[x][y]) {
                // What to add??
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have solved this yourself in plain English, which is a step away from psuedocode and therefore two steps away from java code. Iterate through the entire array, and search for two values that have changes. If they are adjacent, you can convert that into a move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the user can only make a move over the empty places(0).
You can do something like this:

```
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
          for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            // Check where not equal
            if (initialBoard.grid[x][y] != newBoard.grid[x][y] && newBoard.grid[x][y] == 0) {
                // From move
                String from = x +""+ (char)y+65;
            }
            if(initialBoard.grid[x][y] != newBoard.grid[x][y] && newBoard.grid[x][y] != 0) {
                // To move
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find two spots where the boards differ. You already seem to have the logic down to find a spot where the game board has changed. Now you need to decide what direction the move occurs in.

To me, it looks like the board going from 0 to 4 means a piece has moved there. So, if the new int is > the old int... we know this is the *end location*.

Since you've gotten this far, I think you can figure it out with the follow logic: (**maybe there are cases in this game I am not aware of - so you will have to check for those cases**)

```
String startPos, endPos;

for (int y = 0; y < Board.DIMENSION; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < Board.DIMENSION; x++) {
    // Check where not equal
    if (initialBoard.grid[x][y] != newBoard.grid[x][y]) {
      // if we go from a 0 to a 4, this is the starting position
      if (initialBoard.grid[x][y] < newBoard.grid[x][y]) {
        // translate the location into a position and store it as startPos
      } else {
        // translate the location into a position and store it as endPos
      }
    }
  }
}

System.out.println(startPos + " -> " + endPos); // something like that
```

Comment: Depending on the rules of the board game, there might be a flaw in this logic. Let's say that the next move is a `2` taking a `4`. The from-position in the initial board will have the same symbol as the to-position in the new board.The to-position in the initial board will differ from the from-position in the new board

Comment: @Sam Agreed - and so I suppose this is more of a nicely formatted comment of guidance rather than an answer. Still - you could set up the logic to handle all of these cases in a similar fashion. Or pass these values to some method that does it for you.